# Updating a existing contract with new code and storage

Tags: contract, address, updates

Is it possible to update a existing deployed contract with new code & storage on the same address?

It would be like adding a new version or does the updated contract have to be deployed to a new address?

If it is possible, it would be very cool if the existing contract storage could be used to initialise the new contract storage - where the data can picked and chosen as needed.